# What are the minimun System Hardware Requirements

Tags: ros, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am new to robotics and i intend to make my bachelor level project for Robot Localization with particle Filters.
I have installed ROS with Gazebo to make simulations but it is not working good on my laptop.
So i intend to buy a new system a desktop workstation may be.
But i m not sure that what is the minimum system requirements.

Here is what i have in mind

**Option1:**

HP XW 6400

XEON Quad Core

2 GHz x 2 Processors.
with 8 Mb Cache.

4 GB RAM.

**Option 2:**

DELL T 5400
Intel Xeon Dual Core

3.33 GHz  x 2 Processors

8 Mb Cache

4/8 GB RAM

Please help me on this issue Any suggestion will be appreciable Thanx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34738/what-are--the-minimun-system-hardware-requirements/) by [Neo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2306/neo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2012-06-16**:
Hi Zubair,   Kindly share which config you bought and your experience with that.

**Comment by [Neo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2306/neo/) on 2012-11-30**:
Core i7 - 8 GB RAM -  graphics with 1GB separate memory. with my experience with ROS and memory specs its " The more the Merrier"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would go for the solution with more cores. As ROS is distributed over multiple binaries it naturally scales well with the number of cores.

Also go for 8GB RAM instead of 4GB. It's probably not too expensive, but multiple binaries do in turn each allocate memory.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3